# Reflection: returned methods consist on undeclared parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

A little setup:
I'm trying to create a generic application that is reading and invoking WCF applications based on their ?singleWsdl.
The class here is named WcfFactory.

I've created a solution consisting of a WCF service to test.
The declared methods are as following (Interface)

```
[OperationContract]
string DoWork();

[OperationContract]
string Hello(string FirstName, string LastName);

[OperationContract]
int Power(int Number1, int Number2);
```

My console app that is consuming my library spits the following:

```
DoWork
Returns: System.String

Hello
 - FirstName (System.String, out: False, ref: False)
 - LastName (System.String, out: False, ref: False)
Returns: System.String

Power
 - Number1 (System.Int32, out: False, ref: False)
 - Number1Specified (System.Boolean, out: False, ref: False)
 - Number2 (System.Int32, out: False, ref: False)
 - Number2Specified (System.Boolean, out: False, ref: False)
 - PowerResult (System.Int32&, out: True, ref: True)
 - PowerResultSpecified (System.Boolean&, out: True, ref: True)
Returns: System.Void
```

The SingleWsdl also isn't revealing anything spectacular:

```
<xs:element name="DoWork">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="DoWorkResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DoWorkResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Hello">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LastName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="HelloResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HelloResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Power">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Number1" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Number2" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="PowerResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PowerResult" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element></xs:schema>
```

(apologies, pretty print failed to pretify)

I retrieve a list of Methods which I store in a `MethodInfo[]` object.
On this I call `MethodInfo[0].GetParameters();`

Why is it working for the unparameterized function and for the function containing the strings, but not for the integer one?

And how can I resolve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

For completeness, the part of code that is filling my console application (it's already partially filled for dynamic objects)

```
foreach(var param in meth.GetParameters())
{
    if(fact.assemblyTypes.Where(x => x.Name == param.ParameterType.Name).Count() == 1)
    {
         #region Stuck

         Type typ = fact.assemblyTypes[1].GetType();
         //getparams<fact.assemblyTypes[1]>getparams();

         var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(fact.assemblyTypes[1]);

         var propertyNamesFromInstance = instance.GetType().GetProperties()
             .Where(p => p.CanWrite)
             .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
             .Select(x => x.Name);

         foreach (var test in propertyNamesFromInstance)
         {
             PropertyInfo prop = instance.GetType()
                 .GetProperty(test, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
             if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("- [{0}]: {1} ({2})"
                                , param.ParameterType.Name, prop.Name,     
                                prop.PropertyType));
                     //prop.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(d2Reader[test].ToString(), prop.PropertyType), null);
                  }
                  catch
                  { // property not in scope 
                  }
              }
          }

          #endregion                    
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" - {0} ({1}, out: {2})",
                  param.Name, 
                  param.ParameterType.FullName,
                  param.ParameterType.IsByRef));
     }
}
```

Comment: This is very confusing. If you're trying to invoke the procedure through the WSDL, why are you involving reflection? I would assume if you're involving reflection, then you have a hard reference to the WSDL, which would be pretty much the antithesis of working from the WSDL.

Comment: @David The url of the webservice is a parameter. It's not hardcoded, nor is it my intention. It's supposed to be a generic application. If your confusion is because there is a WCF service in the application, this is just to be able to test a service, even w/o the need of an internet connection or to constantly deploy the service.

Comment: Are you trying to create dynamic proxy for WCF service using WSDL?

Comment: My intention is to read method information and invoke methods from various wcf services. Using the singleWsdl is the easiest way to retrieve Class information and Method information. As shown, for the strings method it works as supposed while for int it does not. Is it not true that they both are considered primitive types?

Comment: Wouldn't fact.assemblyTypes[1] always return the same thing no matter which iteration you're in? Could that be the root of your issue? The next thing I would wonder is why you might be looking at properties. You can't get a property from a method using reflection. Methods don't have properties. I suppose I'm wondering what fact.assemblyTypes actually is.

Comment: In the wsdl the PowerResponse has a minoccurs=0 meaning it doesn't need to be in the payload. An int is not nullable, so to distinguish between 0 and novalue/null it introduces and extra boolean to indicate if the valuetype was specified or not. A string oth is nullable so doesn't need that kind of logic.

Comment: @David Type typ isn't used in this iteration, this was for testing.